# Informatica Rank Transformation with Group By

Tags: sql, informatica, rank, informatica-powercenter

I have a question: if I do a Rank like the next, and I keep the TOP (1) in Informatica MDM, what would return the first of each group or the first of all the results?

- A: Chrity Metta
- B: Christy Mehta, Rob Johnson, John Yang, etc.

I don't know how to run the Data Viewer and each person I ask tells me a different result.

```
SELECT [FirstName]
  ,[LastName]
  ,[Education]
  ,[Occupation]
  ,[YearlyIncome]
  ,[Sales]
  ,RANK() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY Occupation 
                 ORDER BY [YearlyIncome] DESC
           ) AS RANK
  FROM [Customers]
```

<strike>Is this query equivalent to saying this ???:</strike>

<strike>SELECT [FirstName],[LastName],[Education],[Occupation],[YearlyIncome],[Sales] FROM [Customers] GROUP BY Occupation ORDER BY [YearlyIncome] DESC</strike>

[image: Results]

[Informatica Rank transformation by group](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/informatica-rank-transformation-with-group-by/)

Comment: What do you mean by "first of all the results"?

Comment: The two queries are not equivalent. For one thing, your second query won't run at all because you cannot use a non-group-key column in the `SELECT` list of a query with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Dai thanks! I 
I wanted to say: The first result of the whole list of results. The option A, in the image the only the first row.

Comment: Can you not use a rank transformation - group by as firatname, last name  and then pick top 1?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the first result you can use the "TOP 1" operand at select at the first part of the query or by using "limit 1" at the end of the query also, that is gonna show only the first row;

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT [FirstName]
   ,[LastName]
   ,[Education]
   ,[Occupation]
   ,[YearlyIncome]
   ,[Sales]
   ,RANK() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY Occupation 
                 ORDER BY [YearlyIncome] DESC
           ) AS RANK
   FROM [Customers]
  ) where RANK = 1;
```